# How can calculate mpeg2/crc32 in Python?

Tags: python, crc, crc32

I have the crc32 code below.

1. I need to edit this code to calculate the MPEG-2 CRC-32, with the
   polynomial `0x04C11DB7`, initial value `0xffffffff`, and final
   exclusive-or with `0x00000000`.
2. I need to calculate the CRC on a specific range, say from offset `0x0` to
   `0x1000`.
3. What is: `buffersize = 65536`, and when can i change it?

---

```
import zlib
buffersize = 65536
with open('file', 'rb') as afile:
    buffr = afile.read(buffersize)
    crcvalue = 0
    while len(buffr) > 0:
        crcvalue = zlib.crc32(buffr, crcvalue)
        buffr = afile.read(buffersize)
print(format(crcvalue & 0xffffffff, '08x'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #1:

```
def crc32mpeg2(buf, crc=0xffffffff):
    for val in buf:
        crc ^= val << 24
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = crc << 1 if (crc & 0x80000000) == 0 else (crc << 1) ^ 0x104c11db7
    return crc
```

replaces `zlib.crc32()`, which computes a different 32-bit CRC. Also the initial value is not zero, so start with `crcvalue = crc32mpeg2(b'')`.